# How to automatically update view of the activity when the data changes?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I want to Update Profile Picture in my app. Every Time User updates his profile picture. But the Problem is Profile picture is only updating when i restart the app after clearing the app from the memory.

The code i want to implement automatically is placed in **onCreate** method.
And the uploaded pic will always be from the internal Storage.   Code is Attached Bellow.

```
mImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_Pic);
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File myImageFile = new File(directory, "my_image.jpeg");
    Picasso.get().load(myImageFile).into(mImageView);
```

I want that the IMageView for the Profile pic is Always updated automatically when the user updates his/her dp.What Should i do or Where Should i place that code?

Comment: How can the user update the picture?

Comment: @RicardoCosteira myImageFile is the directory for the image  and mImageView is the view for it to be uploaded.

Comment: Right, but what user input does the app need in order to update the image?

Comment: there is an editprofile activity where the user make an gallery intent to choose from the gallery. that image is uploded to firebase and a copy of that image is made in the internal storage from where the profile pic is updated because retrieving from the firebase was too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to observe data changes and then update the view in the livedata's observer. If the internal storage was managed by [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), you could make it return a Livedata and go from there.

At a glance, I would do something like this (using Kotlin here, but I'm sure you'll understand):

1. Create a [view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiA-JXiBRCpARIsAGqF8wV1XbW4ooWSzIjST84wWPHOIWSs2zZUQeh1Lu4VVPSFFnuJpgS9ceMaAqTJEALw_wcB) for the Activity, that would manage the Activity state. The view model would have a Livedata of type File:

   ```
   class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {


       private val dataAccess: SomeClassThatControlsDataAccess = ...
       private val _myImageFile: MutableLiveData<File> = MutableLiveData()

       val myImageFile: LiveData<File>
           get() = _myImageFile


       fun updateUserProfilePic() {
         val image: File = dataAccess.getProfilePicFromStorage() // This method would encapsulate that file retrieval code you have on OnCreate
         _myImageFile.value = image
       }
       // other stuff
   }
   ```
2. Observe this in the Activity. Whenever the Activity is resumed and there's a change, the view will be updated:

   ```
   class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       private lateinit var mModel: MyViewModel
       // ...

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

           // Other code to setup the activity...

           // Get the ViewModel
           mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)


           // Observe the LiveData
           mModel.myImageFile.observe(this, Observer {
             Picasso.get().load(it).into(mImageView)
           })
       }


       override fun OnResume() {
           super.OnResume()
           mModel.updateUserProfilePic()
       }
   }
   ```

If you don't want to use any Android framework stuff, you can use something like [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/) and follow a similar approach.

You can also probably just place that code on your OnResume method and be done with it, but that has a tendency of creating a coupled design that’s bug prone and hard to change and/or maintain.

Comment: Can you Please write this line in java (  private lateinit var mModel: MyViewModel )

Comment: `private MyViewModel myViewModel;` or `private MyViewModel myViewModel = null;`

Comment: Brother I did the same. But dont know why its not working

Comment: Well, I can only help you so far :/ I have similar examples to this working in my apps, so it might be some detail that you missed. Try to debug stuff like ensuring that the `updateUserProfilePic` method is called, or that the observer code is reached. I don't know how your code is done, but you can also try to use `_myImageFile.postValue(image)` instead of `_myImageFile.value = image` in case you're using another thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: This can also be related to the way Picasso handles image caching. Only used the library once and for testing purposes though, so I don't know how that works.

Comment: How can i make my own directory . I mean if i want to put my image in the folder called images in the  storage, which I can access later through gallery ?

Comment: That's kinda out of the scope of your question, but you can do so with something like `File imageRoot = new(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "your_directory_name");` to create the directory and then `imageRoot.mkdirs(); File image = new File(imageRoot, "image.jpg");` to create the images.

Answer (score 0):

How is the user updating their profile picture?. You could use Picasso each time the user updates their profile picture.

Comment: I am Using Picasso . But For That I have to restart the app for dp to be actually changed. The Code is Above

Comment: Meant to say, whats your code for allowing the user to update their profile picture?.

Comment: there is an editprofile activity where the user make an gallery intent to choose from the gallery. that image is uploded to firebase and a copy of that image is made in the internal storage from where the profile pic is updated because retrieving from the firebase was too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Picasso in onActivityResult

*edit: added code sample

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE || requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // DO SOMETHING
            Picasso.with(this).load(myImageFile).into(
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate that with an Example ?